# file must not be null when connecting to tfs using sdk

Tags: java, version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am have an application using tfs sdk. It was working fine on my local machine with tomcat. When i deployed it on an ubuntu server I got the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: file must not be null
com.microsoft.tfs.util.Check.throwForNull(Check.java:135)
com.microsoft.tfs.util.Check.notNull(Check.java:28)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.workspacecache.internal.InternalCacheLoader.loadConfig(InternalCacheLoader.java:89)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.Workstation.&lt;init&gt;(Workstation.java:150)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.Workstation.getCurrent(Workstation.java:206)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient.&lt;init&gt;(VersionControlClient.java:450)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient.&lt;init&gt;(VersionControlClient.java:520)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.client.DefaultClientFactory$7.newClient(DefaultClientFactory.java:238)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.client.DefaultClientFactory.newClient(DefaultClientFactory.java:91)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.getClient(TFSConnection.java:1470)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WITContext.&lt;init&gt;(WITContext.java:83)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.getContext(WorkItemClient.java:423)
com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.getProjects(WorkItemClient.java:359)
```

I found a similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f41ba1fb-6aa3-43c2-9a84-61a45914a63e/nullpointerexception-when-attempting-to-connect-to-tfs-server?forum=tee), however i did not find the versioncontrol.config file. Any ideas what else can I try?

Comment: also tried clearing all cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048111/tfs-2010-versioncontrol-config-is-not-valid-and-cannot-be-loaded

Answer (score 0):

1.Check permissions for the file below:/usr/share/tomcat7/.microsoft

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/threadfix/issues/detail?id=184

2.Add administrator user to tomcat-users.xml (under /conf)

Reference:http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html

Comment: what is .microsoft? and why is adding an admin user going to change anything?